# what is `app` in angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

```
  <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
```

what is `app` here ? I am learning `angular 2` .I clone quick start angular project from here 
https://github.com/angular/quickstart
I rename the `app` folder to `d` but still application is running fine .
**systemjs.conf file**

```
  map: {
          // our app is within the app folder
          app: 'd',
```

So I didn't get what is `app` here ?  when I changed `app` to some other name it gives error

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the name from the **systemjs.config.js**, there the 'app' name should link to the compiled **main.ts** file which is **main.js**

So for a short answer is the root javascript(NOT typescript) file from the project, from where angular2 starts the application.

Comment: where app is link ?  could you please tell me I what to change it and try to run this ? can I change `app` to some other name

Comment: Please check my `edit` question I changed `app` folder to `d` and change the value is system.config file

Comment: app is not the app folder. app links to the compiled main.ts file which is main.js, it is not related to the app folder that's something different. So how you said in the systemjs.conf file it links first to a folder(not app, the folder where the files are compiled too) and then it says to load the main.js file from that folder.